# How to use separate MessageConverter for producer in Spring JMS

Tags: spring-jms

I'm looking to receive a message within a method annotated with `@JmsListener` and produce reply to another queue, which expects different message format. Thus I need to apply another `MessageConverter`.

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "request-queue")
public void onMessage(SomeRequest someRequest) {
    var myObject = MyObject.builder()
            .data(someRequest.data)
            .build();

    var someReply = SomeReply.builder()
        .prop(myObject.getData())
        .build();

    jms.convertAndSend("reply-queue", someReply));
}
```

I created two dedicated converters - one for `SomeRequest` and another for `SomeReply`. However, the problem is - injected `JmsTemplate` instance (jms field above) applies only the one of them.

I used `JmsListenerContainerFactory` @Bean to `setMessageConverter`, but I don't know how to force `JmsTemplate` to use `SomeReplyConverter` executing `convertAndSend`.

Any tip would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are defining your own `JmsTemplate` bean, then simply set the converter on it. Show your JMS configuration class(es).

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using two producers and don't know how to control which JmsTemplate is injected (both producers are going to take advantage from different converter)

Comment: Inject them by bean name `@Autowired JmsTemplate oneTemplate`, `@Autowired JmsTemplate twoTemplate`. Or use `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I went for it and it works as I expect. Are you going to add an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining your own `JmsTemplate` bean, then simply set the converter on it.

If you have multiple templates, then inject them by bean name

```java
@Autowired 
JmsTemplate oneTemplate;

@Autowired 
JmsTemplate twoTemplate;
```

Or use `@Qualifier` to specify the bean name.